# WebRTC hardcoded connection (server-less)

Tags: javascript, web, webrtc

I was wondering whether it's possible to use hard coded information in order to establish WebRTC peer connection. I have tried recording the offer, answer and candidates of a normal WebRTC that works well, and then hardcode that info (so there will be no need for the signaling server next time). Unfortunately, it didn't work. Is there a way to hardcode this information and use it in that manner?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are IceCandidate and SDP static?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29390356/are-icecandidate-and-sdp-static)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work that way. Every time peers do data exchange via signaling server (using SDP, in particular) before they could establish direct connection; this data includes network options, media options, possible encryption-related options, etc. So, it just doesn't make sense to hardcode all this data - it mostly contains "one-time" option values.